# Laravel/Microsoft 365 SMTP not sending to Gmail.com from Windows Server (IIS 10)

Tags: laravel, smtp, gmail

I have a Laravel project on a Windows Server (IIS 10). Recently, we have noticed that SMTP notifications never make it to Gmail or Yahoo. They go to any other type of account, but not these two.

We have upgraded our DNS records to the latest SFP, DKIM, and DMARC guidelines for sending, but still no dice. This was a Microsoft 365 account. I also tested another non-Microsoft SMTP account and encountered the same issue.

I uploaded the same Laravel project to a Linux server using the same SMTP credentials, and the emails come through just fine in both Yahoo and Gmail.

There must be some setup of the Windows Server that is causing this as the same SMTP credentials work within the same Laravel project, but just on a different server.

Would anyone know the reason for this?

Thanks.

p.s. I don't have the luxury of just using the Linux server due to our company's setup, so please only answers that help resolve the Windows Server issue. Thanks.